# Concise way of using conditional operator

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I have this code, where `LongMethodWithResult` is a method that takes a long time to run:

```
object o = LongMethodWithResult() == someVal ? LongMethodWithResult() : someOtherResult;
```

Now the `LongMethodWithResult` method is evaluated two times, isn't it?

I know I could write a method that uses variables to store the result of the long method, something like this:

```
public static object ConciseConditionalOperator(object a, object b, object c)
{
    return a == b ? a : c;
}
```

But I would be interested in whether there is a *best* way of doing this, or some functionality served by C# or the .NET.

Any ideas are welcomed!

Comment: In your case can't you do `object o = LongMethodWithResult() == someVal ? someVal : someOtherResult;` ?

Comment: I would as a rule of thumb limit the use of conditional expressions to simple logical expressions without side-effects which trigger a choice between two values. K&R's typical example is choosing between a a plural s and an empty string when they print a text, depending on a number being != 1.

Comment: To avoid @PeterB's  (still insightful) shortcut you could ask for a relation other than identity, e.g. `LongMethodWithResult() <=  someVal ? ...`

Comment: @KMoussa and @Peter A. Schneider you are true, ok, let's say the condition is `LongMethodWithResult() <= someVal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you are right. In your example, the `LongMethodWithResult` is executed twice. To avoid that, you need to first store the result of `LongMethodWithResult`:

```
var result = LongMethodWithResult();
object o = result == someVal ? result : someOtherResult;
```

As Peter B said in your answer, the example you provided is a special case where you don't need that, as when `LongMethodWithResult()`'s result equals a value you already know, there's no need to call it again. You can just return the value you already know.

However, oftentimes the following is necessary:

```
var result = LongMethodWithResult();
object o = result == null ? defaultResult : result;
```

You can, however, replace the last construct with a simple:

```
object o = LongMethodWithResult() ?? defaultResult;
```

Comment: ... and for the latter C# offers the elegant `object o = LongMethodWithResult() ?? defaultresult;`.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Yes I was going to write that but go a call from a customer.

Comment: Bloody distractions from the important stuff ;-).

Comment: Yeah, I cut him off, too. Couldn't concentrate on him anyway. :-D

Comment: Thanks for the conclusion! Further considering, do you thing it'd be useful if C# allowed a syntax something like `(a, b)?: c`, where _a_ and _b_ could be the result of two long-running methods, and the expression would be the same as `a == b ? a /*or b*/ : c`?

Comment: Why? There is already a syntax for that: `a == b ? b : c` :-) I doubt that any other syntax would be easier to understand...

Comment: Because if you use the ordinary conditional operator with two long-running methods like `ThisRunsLong() == ThisIsEvenLonger() ? ThisRunsLong() : otherVal`, then `ThisRunsLong` is evaluated twice, unnecessarily.

Comment: Well, maybe the ternary operator in this case is simply the wrong choice. You can easily get around this by using a traditional an well-understood `if` :-)

Comment: Maybe you're right :-). Thanks for your answers and helpfulness!

Answer (score 5):

In this specific case you could use this:

```
object o = LongMethodWithResult() == someVal ? someVal : someOtherResult;
```

If you prefer a different notation, or if you want to avoid specifying `someVal` twice, then you could create an Extension method (in a static class):

```
public static T IfEqualThenElse<T>(this T valueToCheck, T value1, T value2)
    where T : System.IEquatable<T>
{
    return valueToCheck.Equals(value1) ? value1 : value2;
}
```

Usage:

```
var o = LongMethodWithResult().IfEqualThenElse(someVal, someOtherResult);
```